# Removing image from UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I load a `UIImageView` with an image depending on user interaction.  When the parent view is initially displayed, no image has been selected and the imageview is black.  If the user leaves that view and comes back, the image is still there.  I've tried

```
myImageView.image = nil;
```

upon leaving the view but the image remains.  How can I remove the image so the `UIImageView` appears black again?

The

> UIImageView

is connected through IB.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Setting the `UIImageView` as:

```
myImageView.image = nil
```

is the correct way to clear an `UIImageView`. Are you loading the image when your calling function returns? Is your `UIImageView` being declared, and/or used elsewhere in your main function?

Comment: For some reason, it is working now.  I don't know that I did anything different.  Thanks.

Comment: Agreed; this is how you clear the image. The most likely cause is that the nil assignment is not actually being called.

Answer (score 9):

Try stating `[self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];` after your image setting to nil.  This will trigger a redraw of that element on the next runloop cycle I believe.  Aka you are marking this view as 'dirty' and needs a redraw.

Comment: Not getting enough ups on this one because I think it's the right one in this case.

Comment: After set nil to image, sometime ImageView still cached image and not reDraw, so here is the best solution now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with the UIImageView on my UIButton, where I had set the image using

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Setting it to nil would remove the image, but calling the getter again reset the image. I fixed it with:

```
[button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

instead of

```
[button.imageView.image = nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same problem, no matter I use `myImageView.image = nil` or `[myImageView setImage:nil]` the image still show on the `UIImageView`; assuming either one should works. It spend me many hours to debug and find out where have problem. Finally, I did it by using the following code,

```
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:nil];
        myImageView.image = nil;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

I don't know why, but when I work as an animation then the image can be clear perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to remove the image for a given number of clicks.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onImageTapped:)];

tapGesture.delegate = self;

tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; // no. of taps (clicks) on which you want to remove the image

[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

and give the method's definition:

```
- (void)onImageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{

    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*) recognizer.view;
    [imgView removeFromSuperview];
}
```