# How to remove selected image from image view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, imageview

In my app, i have one method loadImage.
The loadImage method use to add new images into imageView.

```
-(void)loadimage:(int)index
{
  ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*index, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-88)]; // -88(Upper+Lower)

  NSString *imageNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrImages objectAtIndex:index]];
  ImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageNameStr];

  [ScrollView addSubview:ImageView];
}
```

After adding images, i want to remove old images.
The removeImage method use to remove old images from imageView.

How can i create removeImages method to remove selected image?

Comment: If `[arrImages objectAtIndex:index]` is already an `NSString` (I suppose it is), then why are you adding another call to `+ [NSString stringWithFormat:]`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to keep around a list of image subviews. After that , you can call `removeFromSuperview` in the ones you want to remove from the scroll view.

Declare an NSMutableArray to hold the UIImageViews.

First, add this to your loadImage method at the end:

```
[arrayOfUIImageViews addObject:ImageView]
```

Then, to remove the image at index 0, do this:

```
[[arrayOfUIImageViews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview]
[arrayOfUIImageViews removeObjectAtIndex:0]
```

Comment: i have no idea in removing selected image. I mean when i reach index2, i want to remove image from index0. I only want to take index1, index2 and index3 on memory.How can i remove index0 when i reach index2?

Answer (score 0):

you can put unique tag number  to trace which `UIImageView` you want to delete.
In your `loadImage:` method:

```
ImageView.tag = index + numberOffset;
```

`numberOffset` is integer value that you know you are not going to use, so that you can avoid collision

then, to remove image

```
-(void)removeImage:(int)tagIndex
{
    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[ScrollView viewWithTag:tagIndex];
    if (imgView != nil) 
    {
       [imgView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

by calling `removeImage:index + numberOffset`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image view to nil, it is the easiest way to clear it.

```
ImageView.image = nil;
```

As you can note in this answer as well.
[Removing image from UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992059/removing-image-from-uiimageview)